# How server knows either it's a browser request or an api's request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need your help. Can you please elaborate when a sign in request is sent to server via browser or api, how server differentiate between these requests?

Thank you.

Comment: It may not always be possible to tell. A POST request from the browser could look the same as a POST request from another application calling the API. The `User-Agent` string might give it away. In ASP.Net the `IsPostBack` property can detect this. Can you tell us why you want to know?

Comment: Let's turn the question around: why do you care where the request comes from?

Comment: because I'm a beginner and my instructor gave me this task to ask on stackoverflow about this scenario.

Comment: @SteGriffiths That's *not* what `IsPostBack` does at all.

Comment: @SteGriffiths And you're talking about WebForms, not MVC.

Comment: @Owais Your instructor told you to ask a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The server really just has a trust the client on this one.  It is commonly done via the [`User-Agent header`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), but I've seen other specialized headers.  If the client "lies" there really is no way for the server to know about it.  There could also be a specialized API end-point just for API based clients, but there is no way to enforce its use or restrict it to APIs only.

Comment: A HTTP client is a HTTP client, whether it's a browser or some other client program, there should really be no reason for the user to care. If you want to try to restrict who can make requests to a particular server endpoint, you can use authentication, and/or techniques such as CSRF tokens which may help to distinguish whether the client is one you want to talk to or not, but does not tell what _type_ of client it is. User-agent strings can be used for that, as others have mentioned, but they're complex and varied, and also very easy to spoof, so you can't rely on them.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer that might be helpful: [How do I determine if a HTTP request came from a browser or something else like a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10034783/9770208)

Also have a read of this little article about ASP.NET API authentication: [Basic Authentication in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication)

#### In Short:

If it is simply an HTTP request then you cannot know. Otherwise if you're developing an API there are techniques used for authentication of the client as it's described in the second link I put above.

Hope this helps.